# How to remove revision number from Visual Studio C# executable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to remove the revision number part from a Visual Studio built C# executable. I have updated the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion with the string "1.2.3". Now, when I right click on the exe and see its properties, Windows shows the product version as 1.2.3 and the file version as 1.2.3.0. Somehow, the 0 gets appended by Visual Studio. Please suggest how I can avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in EXE files [is a `VERSIONINFO` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx), and the version number is four 16-bit integer values representing each component. You cannot select which components are displayed, Windows will always display all four integer values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been trying to setup a build automation setup with Jenkins. So far, I have configured it to use hard coded major/minor numbers and use the build number from Jenkins. When I specify the AssemblyVersion as "1.2.build_num.*", VisualStudio doesn't build. I guess it accepts only either 1.2.3/1.2.3.4/1.2.*. Since we are using Git, I am not sure where I can get the revision number from.